# Validating signing certificate when using OpenId Connect

Tags: certificate, jwt, openid-connect, identityserver3

I'm trying to understand whether my Owin-hosted Web Api needs to validate the certificate used to sign a JWT-token.

I've set up an identity provider using [IdentityServer](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3).  On the "relying party"-side, I have an ASP.NET WebApi hosted using Owin. On the RP-side, I'm using UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication to install the OpenIdConnectAuthenticationMiddleware in the Owin pipeline.

What's working so far:

1. Any unauthenticated user visiting my web app is redirected to the login page on IdentityServer
2. The user logs on
3. The user is redirected back to my web app
4. My web app receives the JWT containing the id token and access token
5. My web app calls the user info endpoint to retrieve the claims using the access token

What I'm missing is logic to validate the certificate which was used to sign the JWT containing the identity token.

Using Fiddler, I've been able to see that the OpenIdConnectAuthenticationMiddleware retrieves the keys from the identity server (by calling https://myidentityserver.example.com/core/.well-known/jwks HTTP/1.1)

Is the OpenIdConnectAuthenticationMiddleware performing some kind of validation of the certificate? Or should I be writing this code myself?

Answer (score 1):

The flow you describe relies on the fact that the verification certificate is pulled from a TLS protected endpoint (JWKs URL) that presents a valid SSL server certificate. This SSL server certificate guarantees that you're talking to the right OpenID Connect provider.

Answer (score 0):

Found some explanations [here](http://leastprivilege.com/2015/11/25/reference-tokens-and-introspection)

For validating reference tokens we provide a simple endpoint called the access token validation endpoint. This endpoint is e.g. used by our access token validation middleware, which is clever enough to distinguish between self-contained (JWT) and reference tokens and does the validation either locally or using the endpoint. All of this is completely transparent to the API.

You simply specify the Authority (the base URL of IdentityServer) and the middleware will use that to pull the configuration (keys, issuer name etc) and construct the URL to the validation endpoint

Comment: I don't think really applies. It seems like this is used when you only have an API and you assume that requests which comes in already contains a token from the start. In my case I want the full implicit flow. It seems like the validator is to be used in the resource owner/client credentials flow.